# Specifying allowed client SSH key types that the server accepts

Tags: ssh, sshd, key-authentication

I have a server (running openssh 8.1p1-2) with sshd_config configured like this to accept only ed25519 keys:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519
```

That works great for our team. We all use only ed25519 keys. And the directive is working correctly because other key types are rejected.

However, now I have the need to temporarily let a person connect who can only use an rsa key type (by policy they cannot control).

I made the following change:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519
```

...  and restarted sshd:

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

According to `systemctl status sshd`, sshd status is error-free. However, when this person tries to connect server logs show:

```
sshd[12345]: userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes [preauth]
```

The error on the client side is simply:

```
No more authentication methods to try. user@ip: Permission denied (publickey).
```

**I do not understand the issue because `ssh-rsa` is in the PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes. What am I missing?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just run into this issue... I needed to add key type rsa-sha2-512 instead of ssh-rsa. (There is also an rsa-sha2-256, which I did not need).

I'm using OpenSSH_8.2p1 on Arch.

Answer (score 5):

I just struggled with this for far too long this morning on an Oracle Linux box.

If you are running on the same or on any other RedHat based distribution, check that your `sshd_config` settings aren't being overridden by those of the system's default crypto policies.  See the man pages for `update-crypto-policies` and `crypto-policies` for details.

`/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensshserver.config` should show the settings currently being applied by the policy for the OpenSSH server.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I am not finding anything related to `crypto-policies` on Ubuntu or Arch Linux.

Comment: Thank you. The same issue on Fedora 33